# Jquery slice not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to use https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/sGkvH for the blog posts on the homepage of blog.raceit.com

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('.load-item').slice(1, 4).show();


$("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".load-item:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
    if ($(".load-item:hidden").length == 0) {
        $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 1500);
});

});



$('a[href="#top"]').click(function () {
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
}, 600);
return false;
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('.totop a').fadeIn();
} else {
    $('.totop a').fadeOut();
}
});
```

Css is hiding the posts.

Seems that maybe I'm using the wrong Jquery? Please help!!

Comment: `not working` - what do you expect to happen, what happens instead

Comment: It is supposed to show the first 4 posts and when you click the load more button, the next 4 will show. It shows nothing (which is correct because the css hides it first then the js is supposed to bring it back). Feel free to check out the website at blog.raceit.com

Comment: right .. so the codepen does that ... what's **your** problem ... yo've answered the first part of my comment, but ignored the much more important second part of my first comment - because `not working` is just lazy

Comment: I notice you slice (1,4) in the second line of code - what don't you like about the first result?

Comment: The code seems to work.. Please update with a comment or answer if your  question is answered

Comment: `$('.load-item').slice(1, 4).show();` will probably only show 3 items, excluding the first item (item 0 in array terms). `$('.load-item').slice(0, 4).show();` is correct I'd have thought.